# Fusion Tables Layer without markers & infowindows

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-fusion-tables

I'm using Fusion Tables Layer to color in all the countries of the world. Unfortunately there are also markers. And when I click on a country a info window is shown.

I only want the polygons to color the countries, not the markers & infowindows. How can I prevent those from showing.

I have used the layeroption: 'suppressInfoWindow: true', but this does not seem to work.

I have created a [codepen example](http://codepen.io/sjvisschers/pen/GpjxVw)
My fusion table can be found [here](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/data?docid=1czcJKrnxMfRHNlHcMd1C0OjhprGb2pxNS8YjNUvr)

```
var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
  map: map,
  query: {
    select: '\'geometry\'',
    from: '1czcJKrnxMfRHNlHcMd1C0OjhprGb2pxNS8YjNUvr'
  },
  styles: [{
    polygonOptions: {
      fillColor: '#FF0000',
      fillOpacity: 1,
      strokeOpacity: '0',
      strokeWeight: '0'
    }
  }],
  suppressInfoWindow: true
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo.  `suppressInfoWindow: true` should be `suppressInfoWindows: true`

Comment: Thanks, I copied this line from an existing project. It now works!! 
I also found an answer to my other problem. Apparently the markers (or points) were defined in my original KML file I used to full the Fusion Table with.